# Create nested folders into internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I am currently working with **internal storage.** i want to create multiple folders like **mainFolder/subFolder/fileName.**

i already prepare lot of tutorials and i wouldn't find the best solution.. And i am also getting error **java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory).**

***My query was***

- What is this error? *any one can please explain this*.
- How to create folders  in internal storage.

Comment: Are you using runtime permissions? Post code

Comment: Open failed... You're trying to open something as a file, but it's a directory... Self explanatory, but please show code

Comment: "What is this error?" -- you are trying to perform some file operation on a directory instead of a file. Since you declined to provide a [mcve], we cannot be much more specific. "How to create folders in internal storage" -- using standard Java I/O. Use `getFilesDir()` on `Context` to get what you call `mainFolder/`, and create subdirectories from there (e.g., `File subdir=new File(getFilesDir(), "subFolder"); subdir.mkdirs();`). Other than the `getFilesDir()` part, this is not significantly different than working with directories in other Java environments.

Comment: #fillobotto sure i have it!

Answer (score 4):

> **Finally I got this One**

***To create Nested Folders***

**//     Save Internal Storage**

```
File myMainDir = context.getDir("MainFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

File mySubjectDir = new File(myMainDir, "subFolder");
mySubjectDir.mkdir();

File myModuleDir = new File(mySubjectDir, "semiSubFolder");
myModuleDir.mkdir();

File myFinalDir = new File(mySubjectDir, "fileName.mp4");

// Save External Storage

String DNAME = "MainFolder"+"/"+subFolder+"/"+semiSubFolder;
File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), DNAME);
if(!rootPath.exists()) {
    rootPath.mkdirs();
}

if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    Log.v("Cannot use storage","Cannot use storage");
}

File myFinalDir = new File(rootPath,"fileName.mp4");
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. mkdir commands work, but not the myFinalDir part that should create a file.

Comment: Or then you might be missing .createNewFile() for myFinalDir?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

String folder_main = "NewFolder";

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

If you wanna create another folder into that :

```
File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + folder_main, "product1");
if (!f1.exists()) {
    f1.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: i wanna create internal only not external storage.